# Real Time Excel Calculation in powerpoint

Tags: excel, ms-office, powerpoint

I know I can input an excel sheet into a ppt. But is it possible to allow a value in an earlier slide to be used within the ppt?

For example.  Slide 3 has "expenses" but if you change some value on that page some cell value changes to reflect the new value on slide 3.

Comment: If you go the VBA route, a good starting point might be [responses here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16591029/4780877

Comment: The code to pick up a value from one slide and use it in another is trivial.  ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes(42).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(42).TextFrame.TextRange.Text  (where 42 is some actual value for the target slide and source/target shapes).  Getting the code to RUN is trickier.  Will this happen during a slide show or at some other time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking this page up. You can pick the appropriate office version. The proper approach would be using VBA.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff746073.aspx